# MS Access syntax error when updating on join

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am receiving

> Run-time error '3075' - "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ct.ContainerID FROM tblCrossarm AS mt INNER JOIN tblContainerTemp AS ct ON mt.SerialNumber = ct.SerialNumber

At the time of the failure, the strSQL variable looks like:

```
UPDATE mt SET mt.ContainerID = ct.ContainerID FROM tblCrossarm AS mt INNER JOIN tblContainerTemp AS ct ON mt.SerialNumber = ct.SerialNumber
```

**Code**

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database: Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim arrMaterialType() As String
    Dim rstContainerTemp As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstMaterialType As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strContainerID As Variant: strContainerID = Null

    If IsNull(cboContainerID.Column(0)) Or cboContainerID.Column(0) = "" Then
        If MsgBox("You have not selected a Container ID." & vbCr & vbLf & "Press OK to Delete the Container IDs of all materials in the Container Table or press cancel to abort.", vbOKCancel, "Delete Container IDs?") = vbCancel Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        strContainerID = Chr$(39) & cboContainerID.Column(0) & Chr$(39)
    End If


    Set rstMaterialType = dbs.OpenRecordset("qryDistinctMaterialType")
    Set rstContainerTemp = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblContainerTemp")

    If Not (rstContainerTemp.EOF And rstContainerTemp.BOF) And Not (rstMaterialType.EOF And rstMaterialType.EOF) Then

        rstContainerTemp.MoveFirst
        rstMaterialType.MoveFirst

        Do Until rstMaterialType.EOF = True
            Do Until rstContainerTemp.EOF = True

                If rstMaterialType.Fields(0) = rstContainerTemp!MaterialType Then
'                    rstContainerTemp.Edit
'                    rstContainerTemp!ContainerID = strContainerID
'                    rstContainerTemp.Update
                    strSQL = "UPDATE tblContainerTemp AS ct SET ct.ContainerID = " & strContainerID & " WHERE ct.SerialNumber = " & Chr$(39) & rstContainerTemp!SerialNumber & Chr$(39) & ";"
                    dbs.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

                End If

                rstContainerTemp.MoveNext

            Loop

            rstMaterialType.MoveNext
        Loop

    End If


    strSQL = "UPDATE mt SET mt.ContainerID = ct.ContainerID FROM " & cboMaterialType.Column(0) & " AS mt INNER JOIN tblContainerTemp AS ct ON mt.SerialNumber = ct.SerialNumber;"
    dbs.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

    dbs.Close
    Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, `UPDATE` statements do not use `FROM` clause. Simply adjust query to:

```
UPDATE tblCrossarm AS mt 
INNER JOIN tblContainerTemp AS ct ON mt.SerialNumber = ct.SerialNumber
SET mt.ContainerID = ct.ContainerID
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Why is it that MS built both Access and SQL Server with the intention of them working in tandem, yet they have two totally different syntax for a minority of their statements? They're so similar that anomalies like this are infuriatingly difficult to remember and find when searching on the internet.

Comment: No problem. Both these databases are two different products with different technologies who share the same vendor. SQL has many dialects that vary slightly. In fact, Access's `UPDATE` is closer to MySQL's!